# php, cookies, wordpress - how to make automatic login in one one site, login and on other one

Tags: php, wordpress, url, cookies, httprequest

Hi i have two wordpress sites, that are almost identical but have different domains.

What i need to make is when you login on one site of wordpress that it would login with same username and password on other site.

I know this could have some security issues, but this does not matter i just need to make this task.

I know the principals, how it should work, one page in login request other to login user with same username or other way around when you go into one site it checks if user is logged in in other one.

But how to do so in code ? php, wordpress, cookies ?

Ideas ? Functions ? How to send request by php ?

Thank you

Edit : Users are synchronized on both sites, user should not be able to see anything about second login. How to send such url request via php ? User logins in in one site by entering username and password it is automatically logged to other, if he come to second site he is already logged in.

RIP Steve Jobs !

Answer (score 0):

Either you add the login and password to the URL to the other site or out could use an iframe or popup to open the other site for login, having the other site setting its cookie.

It all depends on how the user is intended to switch between sites.

Should there be links or might they open the sites independently?

Added solution.

One site could possibly redirect the user after login to the other site with a link that does the login, then the other site immediately redirects back to the original site.

This way you will not have problem with blocking 3:d party cookies.

But you will need to make a special login page for the redirects.

Comment: They are independent. User should not see the login to other site at all. User enter login information to one site, and system should login them to both of them. User should not see the other login. How to make such url request ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier to put one site in charge of logins in a master-slave relationship. Otherwise you get into a mess with conflicting lists and no audit trail.

Have you considered one of the plugins that work with the various auth servers like Google etc.? Then the sites may not need to talk to each other.

There's this from the wordstack site: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3924/synchronize-wordpress-user-accounts-across-multiple-domains-and-installations-wit

EDIT:

There's this to get started.

http://willnorris.com/2009/03/authentication-in-wordpress-28

Maybe you could write a quick json server on each, accessible by the other. I've done
similar in a dozen lines of code or so (but not with wordpress). Let me know if you want more info.

Comment: It is synchronized. I mean all users are the same in both sites. I just need login part now.